# Looking for a way to prevent SWTableViewCell from reverting to scrollStateCenter after tapping disabled button?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am using `SWTableCell`s and in the `rightButtonsArray` I have two buttons. I am trying to disable the buttons but I would also like to stop the scrollview from jumping back to the center.

I checked the rightButtonHandler and all it does is delegate the buttonIndex. I cannot find where the cell state gets changed back to center after the button is pressed.

Is there a way to prevent the `SWTableCell`s from sliding back after the disable button is pressed?

I tried setting this to return false, however the scrollView gets stuck on the entire cell.

```
-(BOOL)swipeableTableViewCell:(SWTableViewCell *)cell canSwipeToState:(SWCellState)state;
```

*Edit*

Got it for those who would like to know. By disabling the button the `tapGestureRecognizer` takes over which be default hides the buttons. My workaround is to set aside a group of tags 500 - 600 for me as "disabled tags" and use if or switch statement to handle the rest.

Comment: Hey Snymax, you can add your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted to help other people with this issue. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it for those who would like to know. By disabling the button the tapGestureRecognizer takes over which be default hides the buttons. My workaround is to set aside a group of tags 500 - 600 for me as "disabled tags" and use if or switch statement to handle the rest.